# why when i close android app, the nativeStorage on ionic not save my data

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problem, when I login to the application. Native storage on Ionic keeps the login result data well but when I close my application, the data on `nativestorage` is gone and also I do not use `this.nativeStorage.remove()` command. Anyone know what cause this? And how to solve it?

This is the login data when I logged in

```
{
"phonenumber":"12341234",
"username" : "bingo"
}
```

but when I close the application

```
{
"phonenumber":"",
"username":""
}
```

Comment: Are you using Ionic Storage?

Comment: ya, i'm using ionic native storage @BaadierSydow

Comment: What does your IonicStorageModule.forRoot() in your app.module.ts look like? Is it the default configuration?

Comment: Do you have this up on a repository that I can look at too?